# R - work within a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to operate with some variables `(v1, v2 and v3)` of a data frame (`A`).
Here's what I want to do:

```
sum(A$v1*A$v2)/sum(A$v3)
```

It's annoying to write every time `A$varname`, how can I tell R to work with that dataframe?

I've seen I can write:

```
attach(A)
sum(v1*v2)/sum(v3)
detach(A)
```

but I guess there should be something easier.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `with()` for that purpose:

```
with(A, sum(v1*v2)/sum(v3))
```

This will also be "safer" than using `attach()` and `detach()` and hence is considered better practice than `attach()`